# PHP/Firebird DB - Connecting to DSN with no password

Tags: pdo, odbc, firebird, password-protection, dsn

A friend is working with a company who's software vendor allows ODBC/DSN connections but refuses to give a username and password.

Is it possible to connect to ODBC/DSN with no password? I have never had to do this so I wasn't sure what to tell him. Everything example I have looked at, connecting with PHP, shows a username and password.

Comment: If you down vote, have the decency to explain why... Generally a down vote is because there isn't enough info in the question, I am very limited to what I know in this case. it should be fairly simple to answer yes/no it can/can't be done, then I know not to waste my time. I did search, but info is limited on it. When you down vote, it hinders other, actual helpful, people from even looking.

Comment: You could always open the database under a Firebird server with a known password instead of depending on the whims of your vendor. Passwords are part of the server install (at least Firebird 2.5 and earlier), not of the database itself.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel - and then to grant all required roles, and detect if ?SYSDBA role was created, etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firebird has so called "Trusted Authentication", when the connection is made by automatically detected current Windows (Linux, etc) user.

- https://www.firebirdsql.org/manual/qsg2-config.html
- https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/fblangref25-en/html/fblangref25-security-auth.html
- https://github.com/FirebirdSQL/firebird/blob/master/doc/README.trusted_authentication

This, however, is not the most frequently used scheme, and there were a LOT of bug reports for it on the tracker.

Additionally, Firebird Embedded may be used, that works like SQLite, being not a separate process, but merely a DLL/SO library that your program uses to read the database file. In this case no authentication is required also.

So, all in all:

- Yes, it is theoretically possible to switch Firebird server into Trusted Authentication, where no explicit username and password would be needed, and your case MAY be one of those.
- Yes, some applications are quite content with Embedded library rather than a full-featured standalone Firebird SQL Server, and that mode has no authentication at all.

But those options are not mainstream. For typical connection the username and password must be explicitly provided to the server. And here is another question, where are they stored the credentials, and who provides them? Will it be your application or some library your application uses?

In the PHP samples you saw the name/password were provided explicitly by PHP code, and that is the typical scenario of writing applications. But I am not very versed with ODBC. Is it possible in ODBC to record credentials into DSN properties? So that application would not have to provide them, letting ODBC library to implicitly pass them from its settings? I am sure BDE can do it, you can save login/password in BDE Alias property, and then applications can use that alias without providing credentials on their own. Check DSN properties in ODBC, I think perhaps username and password are already entered there.

Thus your question *Is it possible to connect to ODBC/DSN with no password?* would not have a clear answer. It is *not* possible to connect a regular server without any password at all, but it *is* possible to setup the environment, where your application would not use passwords explicitly, as those were entered in-before in the ODBC level below your application.

PS. for the record, Firebird credentials also can be saved as environment variables, but those only would be Firebird command-line utilities acknowledging them. https://www.firebirdsql.org/manual/isql-environment-variables.html